# Google Sheets / Form Insert New Row at the Top

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with Google Sheets. I recently created a Google Form that allows people to leave feedbacks however when people fill out the form I do not want the new row on the google sheet to be inserted below I want the row to be inserted at the top.

I've tried using this code below however it does not work.

```
function rtoFeedbacks() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bXqkYxQKvPg3urAdsadxdsaDW8KvwEOa9P47PpE");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Feedback Form");
  sheet.insertRowsBefore(2,1);
}
```

New row still insert a the bottom

Comment: does your google form include a timestamp when it writes to the google sheet?  If so, would sorting by the timestamp work, having it sort so newest shows first on top??

Comment: A good suggestion from @MarkB. In fact, I think you'll find that the first field on every Response sheet is a timestamp. The sort could be triggered by `onFormSubmit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, so if that is the case of having timestamps, using:

```
range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false}); //or ascending: true
```

if there is a header row that you don't want included in the sort so it stays up top use:

```
setFrozenRows(1)
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setfrozenrowsrows

I tried this out and it works for me:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.setFrozenRows(1)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false});
}
```